# Passing values from my Java program into GLSL using lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

Lets say I have a fairly complex frag shader for figuring out just how much light goes to each pixel:

```
//shaders/screen.frag
varying vec4 vertColor; //unlit color
float intensity = 1.0; //lighting intensity.

//parameters vary from material to material:
float roughness_rms; //root-mean-square roughness (um).
float peak_angle; //how steep peaks are on average.
/* more parameters */

void main(){
    /* complex shader code to calculate intensity */
    gl_FragColor = intensity*vertColor; //set the light strength
}
```

Here is how I initialize the shaders:

```
//something.java
import <needed crap>
int shader, fragShader;
shader=ARBShaderObjects.glCreateProgramObjectARB();
fragShader=createFragShader("shaders/screen.frag");
ARBShaderObjects.glAttachObjectARB(shader, fragShader);
ARBShaderObjects.glLinkProgramARB(shader);
ARBShaderObjects.glValidateProgramARB(shader);
```

And how I use them:

```
//something.java
ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(shader);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
//etc.
```

My java code calculates roughness_rms and other parameters form various materials. Furthermore, these parameters change when there are impacts with bullets, etc.
My question is: How can I pass variables from my java to the shader language without regenerating the whole shader and recompiling it (that would be slow). Ideally, every quad I draw I would like to update the shader parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a look at "Uniforms" in [the GLSL Specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.10.6.clean.pdf).

Basically, it's a storage qualifier for shader variables that indicates it will be set from outside of the shader (i.e. the CPU side) and changed less often than your inputs (at most once per geometry batch, not once per vertex).

This variable exists at the scope of the entire program (i.e. vertex shader + fragment shader + optional geometry and tessellation shaders); if you want to use it in, say, the vertex shader AND the fragment shader, you'll need to declare it in both but you'll only have to set it once in your client-side code.

In order to actually set the variable, you need to query the location of the uniform (by name) while your program is active. This location is stable as long as the program isn't recompiled so you can cache it and reuse it if you want. The value you set will also stick as long as the program isn't recompiled.

For example, to set a single float (this is OpenGL 3+; I'm not sure if the syntax is exactly the same below that level).

In your shader:

```
uniform float my_value;
```

In your client-side code:

```
glUseProgram(program_id);
GLint my_value_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "my_value");
glUniform1f(my_value_loc, 1.0);
glUseProgram(0);
```

Here's the reference for [glGetUniformLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) (which is easy to use) and [glUniformXX](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml), which is a little more complex (lots of variants to set ints, floats, arrays, matrices, etc.).

Comment: I can't get these functions working. I try 'ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgram' and it doesn't work. If they are not in the ARbShaderObjects class of lwjgl, then where are they?

Comment: Oh, I got it working. You use the class GL20, and apply the commands to the shader, not the frag shader.

Comment: I can't speak to the specifics of lwjgl (I mostly use OpenGL with python) but I'm amending my post to clarify that uniforms are applied to a complete program, not a single shader.